# MySQL - ODBC connect fails, Workbench connect works

Tags: mysql, sql, database, windows, odbc

I am **trying to install and test a MySQL ODBC Connector** on my machine (Windows 7) to connect to a remote MySQL DB server, but, when I configure and test the connection, I keep getting the following error:

```
Connection Failed
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'root'@'(my host)' (using password: YES):
```

The problem is, **I can connect with MySQL Workbench (remotely - from my local machine to the remote server) just fine.** I have read [this FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/access-denied.html) extensively but it's not helping out. I have tried:

- Checking if mysql is running on the server (it is. I even tried restarting it many times);
- Checking if the port is listening for connection on the remote server. It is.
- Connecting to the remote server using MySQL Workbench. It works.
- Checking if the IP address and Ports of the remote database are correct;
- Checking if the user (root) and password are correct;
- Re-entering the password on the ODBC config window;
- Checking and modifying the contents of the "my.conf" on the remote server to allow connections from all sides (0.0.0.0);
- Including (my host) on the GRANT HOST tables from mySQL (I also tried the wildcard '%' but it's the same as nothing);
- Running a FLUSH HOSTS; And FLUSH PRIVILEGES; command on the remote mySQL server to reset the privilege cache;
- Turning off my Firewall during the configuration of the ODBC driver;
- Checked if the MySQL variable 'skip_networking' is OFF in order to allow remote connections.

What is frustrating is that I can connect with MySQL Workbench on my local machine (with the same IP/user/password), just not with ODBC.

What could I be doing wrong, or what could be messing up my attempt to connect with ODBC?

**Update**: I managed to set up the ODBC driver and get it running correctly on the server side. I can connect there to the localhost using a command line (with the "isql" command). But I still can't connect over remotely with my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Is the password blank?

Comment: No, I have a non-empty password. I tried re-writing it many times, but it doesn't work. I can connect from my machine to the remove server with MySQL Workbench connector, using the same user-password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved.

As it turns out, it was a permissions problem. I ran the following command on the remote server SQL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'(my_host)' IDENTIFIED BY '(my_password)';
```

I had run the previous command, but without the "IDENTIFIED BY" password. Then, to reset the mysql permissions cache, I also ran

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me too only with 64bit odbc driver not for mySQL 32 bit.

Comment: correction only the original MariaDB odbc driver worked. MySQL odbc brougt missleading error.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar case that 'user'@'%' was granted at server but ODBC connect failed at a PC while workbench connect successfully.

MariaDB 10.0.31,
MySQL ODBC 3.51,
MySQL Workbench 8.0

Solved by install MariaDB Connector/ODBC 3.1 instead of the MySQL ODBC (https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-odbc/).